# how to add values from dynamically generated table row to one input box

Tags: javascript

```
function addTotal(){


var txtTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal').value; 

var txtGrandTotal = document.getElementById('txtGrandTotal');

txtGrandTotal.value += parseInt(txtTotal);
}


this is delete code 
$(".delete-row").click(function(){
$("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")){
$(this).parents("tr").remove();
}
});
});
```

if the user deletes the row then the values from the Grand Total Should decrease. anything I should do any body

how to add values to the "Grand Total" to the Total input box Total is the dynamically created table data and I want to add values to that "Grand Total input box" but values are appending not the adding and also I have added an [image]image of the screen or output.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: no bro same result I am getting.

Comment: yes,  I have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
txtGrandTotal.value += parseInt(txtTotal);
```

as `txtGrandTotal.value` isn't converted to `int`, it is `string`

so you should do:

```
if (!txtGrandTotal.value)
    txtGrandTotal.value =  parseInt(txtTotal);
else    
    txtGrandTotal.value =  parseInt(txtGrandTotal.value) + parseInt(txtTotal);
```

Comment: I am getting NaN(not a number) In grand total

Comment: in the same way if I delete the row the value from the grand total should decrease.

Answer (score 0):

hey can I get your source code I need form IP billing master as you have? if you don't mind